# Un objet « a impacté la Terre et s'est désintégré » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, formulation, terminologie, anglicismes, emprunts

> Après avoir survolé la région parisienne et la Normandie, le bolide
> baptisé #Sar2667 **a impacté** comme prévu la Terre vers 3 h (21 h heure
> de l’Est) lundi, et s’est désintégré en entrant dans l’atmosphère près
> des côtes de la Manche. ([Lapresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/sciences/2023-02-13/une-petite-meteorite-a-survole-l-europe.php) via AFP)

L'emploi du verbe [*impacter*](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/impacter) pour « avoir des conséquences » est déjà critiqué et il s'agit ici probablement d'un (autre) [anglicisme](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/impacter) pour « entrer en collision ; heurter ; percuter ». Or la référence à la désintégration dans l'atmosphère rend l'emploi encore moins précis.

- Cet emprunt est-il un terme technique, est-il de plus en plus courant
  ?
- A-t-on une autre suggestion de verbe pour le remplacer ou comment
  peut-on reformuler la phrase ?

Answer (score 3):

*Cet emprunt est-il un terme technique, est-il de plus en plus courant ?*

Il est très courant dans tous les domaines quand il a le sens figuré de l'anglais, un peu moins quand il s'agit du sens propre.

*A-t-on une autre suggestion de verbe pour le remplacer ou comment peut-on reformuler la phrase ?*

Au sens propre, on peut utiliser *percuter*, mais avec ce verbe, on s'attend plus à un choc avec un solide alors que dans le cas de la question, il s'agit d'une collision progressive avec l'atmosphère, qui d'ailleurs n'a été impactée que de façon infinitésimale par cet événement. On pourrait parler de *plonger* dans l'atmosphère terrestre, la *heurter*, la *frapper*. En tout cas, je trouve qu'*impacter* est un emprunt qui s'intègre bien au français et qui est moins lourd qu'un autre néologisme : *collisionner*.

> Après avoir survolé la région parisienne et la Normandie, le bolide baptisé #Sar2667 a heurté comme prévu la Terre.

Comment: En quoi consiste la lourdeur de « collisionner » ?

Comment: @LPH C'est une opinion. *Collisionner* me fait penser à [*solutionner*](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/solutionner).

Comment: Je dis ça parce qu'en anglais il existe « collision » et le verbe,  « collide , et il n'y a pas la moindre idée de lourdeur associée à ce verbe; il n'en faudrait pas plus qu'une longueur légèrement plus grande du mot pour le rendre lourd ?

Comment: @LPH Mais si à la place de _collide_ on avait _collisionate_ (sic)...

Comment: @LPH Si les verbes *collider*, voire *colliser*, existaient en français, je ne les trouverais pas lourds. (élider - élision, diviser-division, "collider-collision", réviser-révision)

Answer (score 1):

Ce n'est nulle part un terme technique ; il est employé dans des domaines scientifiques, mais comme un terme non spécialisé.

> ([Endométriose : Ce que les autres pays ont à nous apprendre](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Endom%C3%A9triose_Ce_que_les_autres_pays_ont/ni14EAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22impacter%22&pg=PT104&printsec=frontcover)) (La substance sécrétée par l'endométriose peut impacter l'ovocyte et le sperme. • La nature inflammatoire de la maladie peut impacter la fécondation et l'implantation de l'embryon, via les cytokines.

> ([Crises épidémiques et mondialisation: Des liaisons dangereuses ?](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Crises_%C3%A9pid%C3%A9miques_et_mondialisation/fdwtEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22impacter%22&pg=PT63&printsec=frontcover)) sécheresses et inondations, ne peuvent qu'impacter les virus, notamment les arbovirus. Il est attendu que le rôle du facteur humain, qui reste prépondérant, soit aggravé par les facteurs climatiques ; en effet, les changements

Ce mot est employé comme "affecter" dans les sciences de la nature, les sciences humaines, les sciences molles et dans de la littérature de vulgarisation, en particulier, le journalisme, et dans de la littérature à sensation.

> ([Profession : Régulateur, tome 6: Flinguer le président, ...](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Profession_R%C3%A9gulateur_tome_6/x4FJDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22impacter%22&pg=PT47&printsec=frontcover))  On savait qui impacter, désormais. Et pour impacter, ça va impacter, crois-moi, Totor. Tiens, suis-moi ! Nous nous retrouvâmes dans la rue et décidâmes de marcher vers notre hôtel. Je réfléchissais aux accès de violence dont les hommes ...

Son utilisation n'a pas cessé de monter en flèche pendant les vingt dernières années.

[image]

Il n'y a pas de verbe unique, mais le plus souvent il est remplaçable par « affecter » ou ainsi que le précise l'Académie, « avoir des conséquences », « avoir des effets », « avoir de l’influence sur quelque chose ». Dans la référence précédente, il est clairement donné à ce verbe un autre sens (il y a une idée de violence à l'encontre de quelqu'un). Dans l'article de La
Presse qui a été cité, il ne peut pas s'agir de « avoir un effet » ; dans ce dernier cas, l'idée de la création d'un impact (physique, [TLFi, A](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/impact)) est très apparemment ce qui a guidé le choix ; encore une fois, il ne s'agit pas de  « avoir produit un effet ».

Il n'existe cependant pas de logique impeccable comme on pourrait le croire sur la base de la prescription de l'Académie, pour bannir ce verbe du vocabulaire, et j'affirme cela en prenant compte des diverses sous-entrées du « B » de « [impact](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/impact) » dans le TLFi. Bien que ce dictionnaire souligne la nature très ordinaire de la langue dans laquelle est utilisé ce mot, on peut se demander si ne lui fait pas défaut le concept compagnon d'un verbe d'action, qui, n'ayant pas pu entrer par la petite porte, serait maintenant en train de passer par la grande.

Answer (score 1):

> ...le bolide baptisé #Sar2667 a
> [**atteint**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/atteindre)/[**rejoint**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rejoindre)/[**rallié**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rallier) comme prévu la Terre
> vers 3 h (21 h heure de l’Est) lundi, et s’est désintégré en entrant
> dans l’atmosphère près des côtes de la Manche.

L'idée d'arriver à un endroit en se déplaçant, de retrouver/venir en contact, de rallier un endroit vers lequel on se dirige etc. de ces verbes les rendent utiles en contexte. On aurait aussi pu se passer de cette précision sans grande différence (« ...le bolide baptisé #Sar2667 s’est désintégré en entrant dans l’atmosphère près des côtes de la Manche comme prévu vers 3 h (21 h heure de l’Est) lundi. »).

Comment: « Atteint », mais difficilement « rejoint », et pas « rallié » (marine).

Comment: @LPH Je trouve _rallier_ moins usuel, mais je ne me laisse pas impressionner par des syntagmes plus courants ; peut-être que je mélange avec _relier_, j'ai pas le temps de me pencher là-dessus pour le moment. Quant à _rejoindre_, je ne vois pas le problème. Dans tous les cas c'est meilleur qu'_impacter_ surtout qu'il n'y a aucun impact ici.

Comment: «  Qqc. rejoint qqc. Retrouver en un point; venir en contact. Un désert de terre nue, coupé de grandes lagunes, incroyablement plat et rejoignant la mer  » : pas de mouvement ; tout le reste c'est « Qqn  rejoindre  qqc/qqn » ou joindre ce qui a été séparé.

Comment: [_Gagner un lieu_](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rejoindre/67807). C'est discutable. @LPH

Comment: Celui-là non plus ! Pas idiomatique…

Comment: @LPH Tu devrais cliquer sur le lien, c'est un des sens de _rejoindre_ sur Larousse ! C'est en réponse à ton commentaire sur les sens de _rejoindre_ et la prétendue absence de mouvement... _Atteindre_ est sans doute le meilleur des trois, je te l'accorde.

Comment: Il faut une idée de but (il gagne la porte, il gagne un siège, l'astronef gagne la terre) ; il n'y en a pas dans le cas des météores.

Comment: @LPH N'oublie pas qu'on parle de _rejoindre_. On peut rejoindre Paris par l'autoroute, et de là, on peut s'abîmer dans la Seine ou continuer notre chemin... ;-) _S'est abîmé_ !

Comment: Un petit jeu de mot: *a téléscopé la Terre* :-)